# How to configure Facebook webhooks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I want to configure [Facebook webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) for the application I'm developing.

What I did so far was:

1. Create FB app
2. Go to app settings and create a new webhook:

   1. Add a valid callback URLs
   2. Choose particular fields
3. Successfully save the settings

Now, when I'm querying for page subscriptions I get the response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "page",
      "callback_url": "CALLBACK_URL",
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ],
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

which seems to be valid.

What should I do next? How to start listening from feed of a particular page?

Comment: Quote from the very page you linked to: _"page-related RTU objects will require that your app be installed on the page. [...] You can install the app for a Page using the /{page-id}/subscribed_apps edge."_

Comment: I am not getting any response after setup the call back. I just got  custom token value and challange value while validating the callback.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the entire configuration for [Receiving API Updates in Real Time with Webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) :

## Step 1

1. [Create Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/)
2. Go to https://www.facebook.com/pg/YOUR_PAGE_NAME/about/?tab=page_info and read `Facebook Page ID` at the very bottom.

## Step 2

1. [Create a developer account and a Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register)
2. Copy your `Facebook App ID` described in the above point.

## Step 3

1. Create a server application that will handle your Callback URL. A few examples are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples).
2. [Set up your Callback URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) in the Facebook application you created in the previous step.

## Step 4

Subscribe you Facebook App to your Facebook Page. To do that open [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

1. Obtain Page Access Token
   [image]

Make sure you selected your particular application.

2. After granting the permissions, select your particular page. The token will be put in `Access Token` field.
3. Make [POST request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps) to the particular URL:

   ```
   /YOUR_PAGE_ID/subscribed_apps
   ```

## Summary

That's it! With these steps you should have your server application up, running and listening on all events you declared!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I tried however did not work well in my case, but the difference what I developed is the page was already published without messaging events. Do you think it changes something for webhook?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.

Comment: So, basically, all steps are done and when I trigger a webhook with test button it fires, however message conversations are still not triggering the server. What I am thinking is, is there any chance for that case the problem can be a difference between already published facebook page and not published page.

Comment: Is validation webhook going through?

Comment: I am not sure, how can I check that?

Comment: @kamil, yes my validation is perfectly getting response. But not getting page detail after adding subscribe.

Comment: @YigitAlpCiray its exactly the same for me, its triggered by test button, but not with the real page evenets, did you find the reason for that? Any solution? Mybe it needs preview???

Answer (score 0):

For Django to respond to the VERIFY with a CHALLENGE back, here is a snippet to handle this in the view.py:

```
VERIFY_TOKEN = '******'

def fbwebhook(request):
    if request.GET['hub.verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN:
        return HttpResponse(request.GET['hub.challenge'])
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Error, invalid token')
```

I referenced [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/sukritiverma1996/chat_bot).

Comment: Not familiar with Python. Is this just putting the token in the body of a plaint/text response? The docs don't seem to specify in such detail.